# What does Console.ReadLine() do in this code context?

Tags: c#

What is specific purpose of `console.readline` in this code?

```cs
String username = Console.Readline();
String password = Console.Readline();

String Valid = (username = "Kmp" && password = "Kmp")? "Valid user": "Invalid User";

Console.Writeline(Valid);
```

*I am noob player ;), i need your help as much as you can give.*

Comment: Did you try reading the docs - [readline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netframework-4.8)?

Answer (score 4):

The code above is partially invalid.  To address your primary question, `Console.ReadLine()` will read input from a user in the console window.

```
string username = Console.ReadLine();
```

`username` will be a memory reference of the user input.  Also the type defined is as follows:

> A string is a sequential collection of characters that is used to
>   represent text. A String object is a sequential collection of
>   System.Char objects that represent a string; a System.Char object
>   corresponds to a UTF-16 code unit. The value of the String object is
>   the content of the sequential collection of System.Char objects, and
>   that value is immutable (that is, it is read-only). For more
>   information about the immutability of strings, see the Immutability
>   and the StringBuilder class section later in this topic. The maximum
>   size of a String object in memory is 2GB, or about 1 billion
>   characters.

Now to address this logic:

```
String Valid = (username = "Kmp" && password = "Kmp")? "Valid user": "Invalid User";
```

You have a big issue in that line.

- You do not use `==` which is for equality comparison.

I would likely do the following:

```
public string Authenticate(string username, string password)
{
     if(String.Compare(username, "Example", false) == 0 && String.Compare(password, "Example", false) == 0)
          return "Authenticated.";

     return "Invalid credentials.";
}
```

Then where you have `Valid` you would simply have: `string valid = Authenticate(username, password);`. But instead of returning a string and consuming a message you could write back to the user directly with `Write` or `WriteLine`.

Other conditional approaches you could have done:

```
(username == "..." && password == "...") ? "..." : "..."

if(username == "..." && password == "...") 
{
    // True
}
```

Several approaches, but remember to use `==` for equality, single is for assigning values.

Answer (score 1):

`Console.ReadLine()` is used to read input from console store input into string.

Here in your code, username and password is reading from console and storing it into respective variables

```
String username = Console.Readline();  //Reads input from console and store string value to username variable
String password = Console.Readline();  //Reads input from console and store string value to password variable
```

From MSDN

> Reads the next line of characters from the standard input stream.

[Console.ReadLine Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netframework-4.8)